# cannot set the button border property using css

Tags: css

Come to a strange problem, when I use css to set the button, I can set its color, font-size, background, but cannot set its border. The following is HTML and CSS code.

```css
.btn-general {
  border-width: 2px !important;
  border-style: solid !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 12px 26px 12px 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.btn-white {
  border-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">

  <div id="home-cover">

    <div id="home-content-box">

      <div id="home-content-box-inner">

        <div id="home-heading">

          <h3>Watch Out<br>The Modern Responsive Website!</h3>

        </div>

        <div id="home-btn">
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#work" title="View Our Work">View Our Work</a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: don't mix html and css like that. if you want to use css within your html then use the `style` tag and make sure it's within the `head` tag. that should solve your problem.

Comment: put your css on the top of html

Comment: If you are using some other CSS in addition (bootstrap, jquery-ui, etc) you might need to add !important.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just setting a white border on a white background container?

Comment: I mean, even without changing anything in your code, you can clearly see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/eg43u04d/

Answer (score 0):

Put your css in **Style Tag**

```
<style>
    .btn-general{
    border-width:2px !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 12px 26px 12px 26px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }

    .btn-white{
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    }
    </style>
```

**always put CSS on the top of html**

```
        <div id="home-cover">

            <div id="home-content-box">

                <div id="home-content-box-inner">

                    <div id="home-heading">

                        <h3>Watch Out<br>The Modern Responsive Website!</h3>

                    </div>

                    <div id="home-btn">
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#work" title="View Our Work">View Our Work</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: I put it into the css file and link css to html

Answer (score 0):

You have set your border-color to white that's why you could not see that. I have changed it to darker color so that you can see it.

```css
.btn-general{
border-width:2px !important;
border-style: solid !important;
border-color: #ff3333;
border-radius: 0;
padding: 12px 26px 12px 26px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase !important;

}

.btn-white{
color: #222;

border-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">

        <div id="home-cover">

            <div id="home-content-box">

                <div id="home-content-box-inner">

                    <div id="home-heading">

                        <h3>Watch Out<br>The Modern Responsive Website!</h3>

                    </div>

                    <div id="home-btn">
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#work" title="View Our Work">View Our Work</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: actually, the background of the page is black